# Comparison of two columns when they can both be null

Tags: mysql

I want to compare two columns. They must be equal or they both must be null.

```
(t1.id is null and t2.id is null) or (t1.id = t2.id)
```

They are both indexed but MySQL does not use this index probably due to null values. Is there a way to do this where we can benefit from the indexes?

Comment: Issue might be due to ```or```. If first condition including null comparison is met second might not get checked and hence no index usage. Try and re-write as ```(t1.id = t2.id or t1.id is null) AND (t1.id = t2.id or t2.id is null)```

Comment: Please include the query that you want to optimize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Standard (SQL:1999 - Section 8.13) defines the operator `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` for this purpose. It's implemented in MySQL as `<=>`.

For example:

```
with
t as (select 123 as a, 123 as b
      union all select 123, null
      union all select null, 123
      union all select null, null
)
select *, a <=> b from t;
```

Result:

```
 a    b    a <=> b 
 ---- ---- ------- 
 123  123  1       
 123  null 0       
 null 123  0       
 null null 1
```